# Keeping track of tree node's parent in Python

Tags: python

I have a tree of numbers. Each node can have a left and a right child node. Numbers can't repeat but they can be anywhere on the tree. I need to search for a number on the tree and then print it's pathway to the root of the tree.

I can't figure a way to make a node keep track of who is it's parent so I could print them back to the root. How could I accomplish this?

Code as follows:

```
# The Tree class holds a value and left and right childs
class Tree:
    def __init__(self, value, left=None, right=None):
        self.value = value
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

# recursive function that searches the tree for a node
# and alerts when the node is found
def searchNode(tree, node):
    if tree == None:
        return
    else:
        searchNode(tree.left,node)
        searchNode(tree.right,node)
        if tree.value == node:
            print "Node " + str(node) + " found!"

# manually creating a tree with its subtrees
tree1 = Tree(1,Tree(40,Tree(33,left=Tree(204)),
    Tree(21,left=Tree(12,right=Tree(2,left=Tree(32))))),
    Tree(7,Tree(46),Tree(11,Tree(3),Tree(1000))))

# searching tree
searchNode(tree1, 46)
```

Comment: Recursion.  But first you need to learn recursion, and before that... recursion.  Also, when you're done learning recursion, you need to learn recursion.

Also, if you're attempting any recursion, I'd suggest adding defined return statements so you're more likely to properly pass information back up the stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sure you have your reasons for using a tree for O(n) look ups instead of O(log n), i.e., not using a binary search tree, so I won't question that :)

To solve your problem, you can add a third parameter to your function to maintain the path. The following is a very simple and inefficient solution.

```
def searchNode(tree, node, path):
    if tree == None:
        return 
    else:
        #print tree.value
        path.append(tree.value) #add to path because we visited
        searchNode(tree.left,node, path)
        searchNode(tree.right,node, path)
        if tree.value == node:
            print "Node " + str(node) + " found!"
            print path
        else:
            path.pop()  #remove from path because we are going back
```

You will call you function with an empty path: `searchNode(tree1, 46, [])`

Note that the value in `path` will keep on changing even after you have found the element, because nothing is stopping your function from traversing the tree further. You can make your code more efficient by preventing this. If you don't want to do that, copy the value in `path` in some other variable when you find the node, so that you can use it afterwards.

Comment: Pretty simple, and exactly what I was looking for. Thank you, Ali.